# .NET Core GraphQL - GraphQL schema not available and displaying introspection query instead

Tags: .net-core, graphql

I'm using GraphiQL for displaying my schema and querying, as soon as I run my solution, it automatically calls my GraphQL controller and give this on my GraphiQL screen

[image: GraphiQL screen]

and it shows No schema available on the documentation explorer screen.

My schema class -

```
public class GraphQLTodoItemsSchema: GraphQL.Types.Schema, ISchema
        {
            public GraphQLTodoItemsSchema(IServiceProvider provider): base(provider)
            {
                Query = provider.GetRequiredService<TodoItemsQuery>();
            }
        }
```

Type class -

```
public class TodoItemsType : ObjectGraphType<TodoItem>
    {
        public TodoItemsType()
        {
            Name = "items";
            Field(x => x.Id);//.Description("Todo items Id.");
            Field(x => x.Description);//.Description("Todo items Description.");
            Field(x => x.IsComplete);//.Description("Is todo item completed?");
        }
    }
```

Query class -

```
public TodoItemsQuery(ITestRepository testRepository)
        {
            _testRepository = testRepository;

                Field<ListGraphType<TodoItemsType>>(
                name: "items", resolve: context =>
                {
                    return _testRepository.GetTodoItems();
                });
        }
```

I debugged my code, and soon as I ran the solution it gave me this in my GraphQL controller -

[image: Introspection Query]

I read about introspection query, but it didn't helped me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, I tried another extension for graphQL on .net and I've found Banana cake pop to be comparatively easy and straight forward. It gets the job done! Anyone looking for answer can go with the other extension and give it a try!